# If statement in while loop doesn't work

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, nested

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i==0){
        System.out.println("Possibilities: R, T, O and X.\nYour choice: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String bla = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(bla);
        if(bla=="R"){
            System.out.println("S or B?\n Your choice: ");
            String derp = scan.nextLine();
            if(derp=="S"){
                String rekeningNummer = spaarRekening.getRekeningNummer();
                }
        }
        if(bla=="T"){
            System.out.println("dit is T");
        }
        if(bla=="O"){

        }
        if(bla=="X"){

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Impossible. Try again.");
        }
    i+=1;
    }

}
```

I was trying to run this program, but when it comes across an if statement it ignores it. I don't know why and I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To compare `String` instance, use `equals()` since it is an `Object`

**See**

- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: thanks i appreciate it, doesn't state it anywhere in the: _Introduction to Java programming_

Comment: You are welcome, It must be mentioned somewhere in introduction books

Comment: Couldn't find it anywhere, but its not always easy to find things in a book with close to 1500 pages.

Comment: :) then may be change the book

Comment: check appendix for `equals()` it must be there

Answer (score 5):

Use `.equals()` .Don't use  `==` because it compares Strings refrences and not Strings characters.

```
 if (bla.equals("T")) {
     System.out.println("dit is T");
 }
 if (bla.equals("O")) {

 }
```

Comment: thanks i appreciate it, doesn't state it anywhere in the: _Introduction to Java programming_

Answer (score 4):

== is not a `String` comparison operator.

You should use `.equals()` to compare `String`s.

Comment: thanks i appreciate it, doesn't state it anywhere in the: _Introduction to Java programming_

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume we have two strings.
String str1= "blah";
String str2= new String("blah");

There are two levels of equality chacking in Java.

1. You may want to test whether the two referance variable str1 and str2 points to the same String object. we usually do this check by str1==str2.
2. You may want to test whether Strings referenced by str1 and str2 are equal in their meaning. we usually do this by invoking equals method i.e. str1.equals(str2) or str2.equals(str1).

To be more clear, your statement **"bla=="R""** checks whether referances returned by "**"R"**" and  and **bla** point to the same object or not, which is not actually the thing you want.
You want to check whether String referanced by **bla** is equal to "**R**" by meaning or not. So If you want to compare objects by meaning in java, you will have to call equals() method on that object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use == use .equals() since it is an String Object